# Change pivot point for Activity Dynamically

Tags: java, android, animation

How can I change pivot point for `overridePendingTransition` Xml dynamically?

```
a.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.unzoom_in, R.anim.unzoom_in);
```

I have to change pivot point for `unzoom_in.xml` but dynamically. Please help ..!! Thanks in advance..!!